# String concatenation in SQLITE with NA values?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Currently working in SQLite and have the following table

```
id subject_1  subject_2 
1  maths       algebra
2  english     <NA>
3  french      speech
```

I would like to create a new column - which is the concatenation of the columns subject_1 and subject_2, however I have  values within my subject_2 column - is there a way of concatenating the columns so that I can get the following table

```
id new_col
1  maths algebra
2  english
3  french speech
```

Now i have tried the two following methods - both of which did not work; concatenation using || and coalesce (which only takes the first non null value)

```
select
id 
subejct_1 | ''| subject_2 as new_col 
from my_table
```

coalesce is not an option as i would like all string outputs together from both columns.

Is there a way of convering the NA values before hand to an empty string instead?

Comment: Is "NA" the actual string "NA", or a `null`?

Comment: it is `null` the formatting when viewing in a different language makes it <NA>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that `subject_1` does not contain nulls then use `coalesce` only for `subject_2`:

```
select id,
  subject_1 || COALESCE(' ' || subject_2, '') new_col
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ah3SMQpDpFqEf2QKUVNFU5/1).
Results:

```
| id  | new_col       |
| --- | ------------- |
| 1   | maths algebra |
| 2   | english       |
| 3   | french speech |
```

Comment: yes - subject_1 contains no nulls - works perfectly thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't have a `concat_ws` function, at least as far as I'm aware. It's a bit clunky, but you could emulate this with a `case` expression:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN subject_2 IS NULL THEN subject_1 
                                   ELSE subject_1 || ' ' || subject_2
       END
FROM   my_table
```